# ASP.NET MVC2 Strange Validation Problem with Regex (DataAnnotations)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, validation, jquery-ui, data-annotations

I've got my validation wired up through my Service layer, and my Birthdate property looks like this.

```
    <DisplayName("birthdate")> _
    <RegularExpression("^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$", ErrorMessage:="Birthdate is not in the correct format.")> _
    <DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, ConvertEmptyStringToNull:=True, DataFormatString:="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")> _
    Public Property BirthDate As DateTime
```

The client side validation works properly if I input something like `12/12/1990` but when the form is submitted, the server side validation trips and I'm told the entry is invalid.  I'm using the jQuery-UI Datepicker to input the date, however when I disable the datepicker, the problem persists.

Am I missing something here? I thought the client side and server side would be the same thing.

<strike>Afterthought.</strike>

Could it be because I'm using `datetime2(0)` in my SQL Server database?

> I tested the above theory to no avail... same problem.

## EDIT:

If I remove

```
<RegularExpression("^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$", ErrorMessage:="Birthdate is not in the correct format.")>
```

Then the form submits.  It's obviously something to do with the Regex.

## EDIT:

The following code doesn't work either, but I'm wondering if there is a way to modify the modelState to properly set the date before it's passed to the IsValid method?

```
    Dim birthdate As String = user.BirthDate
    ModelState.Item("BirthDate") = DateTime.Parse(birthdate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the user enters `06/27/2010` in the text field and submits the form.

1. The default model binder runs and tries to bind what the user entered to your model. The `BirthDate` property is of type [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) and as you know this type contains an hour part. So now `BirthDate = 6/27/2010 12:00:00 AM`
2. Validation kicks in next. The `BirthDate` property is decorated with the [`RegularExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) attribute so the [`IsValid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679288.aspx) method is called with the string value of `6/27/2010 12:00:00 AM` which fails against your pattern.
3. The corresponding error message is shown to the user.

So the usage of this regular expression attribute is questionable. [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) works fine with string properties though.

If the user enters an invalid date the model binder will protest anyway much before the validation happens. It will also check for invalid days and months which your regular expression doesn't.

Comment: Yes, however I also tried this with the "Date" field in the database which doesn't expect a time field.  Is there a better way to validate the input?

Comment: There's no relation between the type you are using to store the field in the database and the model binding.

Comment: I updated my question a little bit.  Wondering about modifying the ModelState Item before it's passed to IsValid.

Comment: Or are you saying I should just leave it and let the model binder handle it? the only problem with that is that there's no client side validation happening.